# Double Subscript in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, siunitx, subscripts

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{equation}
    2I_{x}S_{z} \overset{\ang{90} \text{Pulse_{I_y}}}}{\rightarrow}
\end{equation}
```

For some reason this is not working. For the overset text, I want a double subscript.
Thank you.

Comment: You have to close the `\text{Pulse}` because if not the superscript is set in text mode. By the way, I would use `\operatorname{Pulse}` or define `\DeclareMathOperator\Pulse{Pulse}` and use `\Pulse`.

Comment: there is also another "extra" close brace following the subscript, after follwing @Manuel's suggestions.  and i'm surprised you didn't get a `! Missing $ inserted.` error.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I got many errors.

Comment: when you get errors, it's important to fix them, starting with the first one reported.  subsequent errors are often just side effects from an earlier one, and will disappear when the initial problem is fixed.

Comment: I would like to point out that `\xrightarrow` and `overset` differ in that `overset` simply "prints" the text above the underset symbol while `xrightarrow` lengthens the underset symbol for better visual effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `_` in the argument to `\text`. You should better use `\mathrm` and `\xrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
2I_{x}S_{z} \xrightarrow{\ang{90}\ \mathrm{Pulse}_{I_y}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Might `\text{Pulse}_{I_y}` be better semantically?

Comment: @Taiki No, it would come out italic if the equation is inside a theorem statement.

Comment: Ah interesting... How about `\textnormal{Pulse}_{I_y}`?

Comment: @Taiki Might be an alternative, but for a single word without special characters, the `\mathrm` solution is more efficient.